VNC live session sharing for 24.04?
I have an issue with remote sharing as follows:
When upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04, the VNC desktop sharing option vanished.
RDP works but, always initiates a blank, new session for the specified user, while a logout closes this session and terminates all processes again.
I am looking for a VNC-like sharing of a running (unlocked) session just like when you would remotely support a user (screen, mouse, keyboard). Any idea?

Is this the host or the guest?

I am talking of the host, formerly with VNC server ("legacy VNC protocol").
